# Simple Contact PHP not sending

Tags: php, contacts, contact-form

I am very new to PHP, I had this working on a windows server, But just recently migrated to a LINUX server and now the form shows as its sending but nothing is coming through? Any help would be greatly appreciated,, Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div id="contact_form">
<form action="html_form_send.php" method="POST">

    <label>
    <span>Name*:</span>
     <br>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name" name="name" id="name" required autofocus>
  </label>



    <label>
    <span>Phone:</span>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your phone" name="phone" id="phone">
    </label>

    <label>
    <span>Email*:</span>
    <input type="email" placeholder="youremail@gmail.com" name="email" id="email" required>
    </label>
         <label>
    <span>Message*:</span>   
    <input name="message" type="text" required id="message" placeholder="Message" value="">
         </label>

  <input class="sendButton" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">

</form>
</div>
```

PHP

```
    <?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: 
$phone \n 
Email:
$email \n 
Message:
$message \n";
$recipient = "dudetotal@gmail.com";
$subject = "Design Contact";
$mailheader = "From: $email \n";
mail($recipient, $subject,$formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");header("Location: http://website.com/website.com/success.html");
```

?>

suggestions?

Comment: It gives a successful message on send,, But nothing shows up?

Comment: Did you check your junk/spam folder?

Comment: 1. Check the error logs. 2. Please, please, please don't use this code. Ever. Using raw data from forms without sanitising is very dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You should use ternary operators, and validate based on the value:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ""; // don't forget to sanitize

if ($name != "") {
    // do logic
}
```

Also, it's pointless to have a header() after the die() statement as the die() statement will end all further execution.

If the email is still not sending, your mail configuration may not be set up properly.

Edit: also look into sanitization. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp) is a link to get you started with it.

Comment: Thanks everyone,,ended up just compiling a new one that is working ..But thanks for all the great info

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

`if ($_POST['name'] && $_POST['email'] && $_POST['phone'] && $_POST['message']) {
   // your email sending logic is here:
} else {
   echo "All fields are required..
}`